# SQL no duplicate timestamps after TRUNC

Tags: sql, timestamp, duplicates

I have a DB with some values, which have a timestamp. What I do is truncate these timestamps to the minute, because the values where measured in a frequency of one minute.
Due to some errors while the measurements sometimes there are two values within one minute. I want to get rid of the second value within the same minute so there is only one value per minute.

```
select trunc(mv.time,'MI') as "minTime",
/*
    get all the required measurement-values
*/
from measurementvalue mv
where mv.MEASUREMENTDEVICE_ID = 1 AND mv.time > '16.03.15 00:00:00'
GROUP BY mv.time
ORDER BY mv.time ASC
```

what I get is something like this

```
     minTIME      | TEMPERATURE | PRESSURE | ...
16.03.15 18:06:00 |   42,1337   |   9000   | ...
16.03.15 18:06:00 |   12,3456   |   1234   | ...
```

but I only want the first line.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `mv.time > '16.03.15 00:00:00'` You are comparing a **datetime** element with a **string**. Never do that, you are relying on **implicit data type conversion**. Also, what **RDBMS product** are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select mv.*
from (select mv.*, trunc(mv.time, 'MI') as minTime
             row_number() over (partition by trunc(mv.time, 'MI')
                                order by mv.time) as seqnum
      from measurementvalue mv
      where mv.MEASUREMENTDEVICE_ID = 1 AND mv.time > '16.03.15 00:00:00'
     ) mv
where seqnum = 1
order by mv.time asc;
```

Comment: `mv.time > '16.03.15 00:00:00'` datetime compared to a string?

Comment: `where seqnum = 1` in outer query ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude first (or last) row if another for same minute exists:

```
select *
from measurementvalue mv1
where not exists (select 1 from measurementvalue mv2
                  where mv1.*down_to_minute_part* = mv2.*down_to_minute_part*
                    and mv2.time > mv1.time)
```

You have to adjust the down_to_minute_part to your dbms' way. (`EXTRACT` is used in ANSI SQL.)